# using sign keyword or select case with orientdb to group by positive and negative

Tags: orientdb

Hi I'm trying to do a queries like the ones below in Orientdb

select sum(opening_balance) from account group by opening_balance < 0

select count(opening_balance) from account group by opening_balance < 0

they run but I'm not getting the desired results in both cases it splits the return by the opening_balance value not whether it is negative or positive.

This is on a graph database

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you attach couple of records for the content and results?

Comment: create class account extends v
create property account.id string
create property account.amount decimal

create vertex account set id='sheldon',amount=-70
create vertex account set id='amy',amount=-70
create vertex account set id='penny',amount=100.75
create vertex account set id='lenard',amount=25
create vertex account set id='raj',amount=25
create vertex account set id='bernadette',amount=21.15
create vertex account set id='howard',amount=0

Comment: when I run the sql from above it groups the records by opening_balance but not by whether or not the value is negative or positive - what I'm trying to see is how many people started with either a negative balance or a positive balance.

Comment: This is SQL, so conditions must be in WHERE, not GROUP BY. Furthermore your examples have amount, not opening_balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SQL, so conditions must be in WHERE, not GROUP BY. Furthermore your examples have amount, not opening_balance.

Comment: yes the example I posted is simple version on what I'm doing I just wanted to sum up the values in the field but do a group by negative and positive amounts - I didn't put the condition in the where clause because I thought it would filter the values out instead of grouping the negative amounts together and the positve amounts together.  I just didn't know if Orientdb sql had a version of select case.  I can just do two queries to pull the results otherwise seperately. thanks